# Android - after editing manifest to disable component will it be always disabled

Tags: android, android-manifest

If i have a broadcastReciever defined in the AndroidManifest as enabled and programatically disable this component -  After a reboot will it still be disabled ?  will it still remember its state after a reboot in other words ?

Would there be any other times that after i disable a component that it can be enabled by the system again ?

here is the method im using to disable/enable the broadcastreceiver component in code:

```
private void setEnabledFromManifest(boolean enable){
     final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        final ComponentName component = new ComponentName(this,
                  MyPhoneStateReceiver.class);
        final int flags = PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP;
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                component,
                 enable ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED:PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                  flags);


   }
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried this on 4.4.3 Android nexus and the change was not remembered after a reboot.  I had to save a shared preference and then install a on boot complete listener. This way i set the preferences if the manifest component should be enabled/disabled on boot complete. The original value in the manifest for the component was indeed remembered after a reboot of the device.

in other words, if your component is disabled from the manifest and you change it in code to enabled, then after a reboot the component will again be disabled(using its initial value).   Thus the answer is NO. Manifest Component status is not remembered after a reboot (at least on Nexus 4.4.3).